# Why function is separated from relation in model definition

Tags: functions, relations, model-theory

A model is defined as a universe together with symbols of relations, functions, and constants.

I find this definition odd because a function can generally be considered a special case of a relation (there is only one value in the range for each one in the domain of the function). So why are function symbols separated from those of relation?

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, but...  If we did specify functions using relation symbols, then in practice one of the first things we'd want to do would be to form the conservative extension by definition - and that extension definitely requires function symbols to make sense out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just makes the matter easier to introduce a function symbol for a definable relation, $R(x, y)$ say, satisfying $$\models \forall x \exists y \big( R(x,y) \wedge \forall z R(x,z) \to z = y \big)$$
We introduce a function symbol , $f_R$ say, and let the theory satisfy $\forall x R\big(x, f_R(x)\big)$. This way, $R$ is the graph of $f_R$ (and, up to the trivial change of language, the models are the same).

For example, sometimes one needs to introduce function symbols to get *quantifier elimination*.

Comment: "the models are the same" is not true (and this is somehow the point of introducing function symbols as special symbols, same as constant symbols): in the relational signature, there exists a structure with a single element $a$ and for which the relation $R(a,a)$ does not hold; in the functional signature, the only one-element structure satisfies $f_R(a)=a$.

Comment: @zarathustra yes thank you for your nice example. There was an implicit assumption : the models (of the theory, $T$ say) are  the same provided $T \vdash \forall x \exists y \big( R(x,y) \wedge \forall z R(x,z) \to z = y \big)$